# Is there a way to create a function that can be either a click event or an onload event, depending on the class of the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically the Title states the question, but the situation is this (it's difficult to replicate with jsbin or anything else, so I'm going to try to solve without doing that).

I have a function that is called on the click of a button.  The click event will tell the output what font will be used.  However, on certain pages, I want the font to be declared by the class of the body element and not on the click of a button.

I'm running into two problems.

1. When I try to pass an argument and receive a parameter, the parameter is an event, rather than whatever I want to pass.
2. If I pass the event as the first parameter and the font I want as the second, I get undefined as my font variable and the function does not work.

Any help on making a function be flexible in this way would help me out a lot.

Edit: Here's a simplified version of what I've got

```
function fontSelection(font) {

var self = $(this),
  inputOne = $('li:eq(0) input').val(),
  inputTwo = $('li:eq(1) input').val(),
  inputThree = $('li:eq(2) input').val(),
  resultOne = $('div:eq(0)'),
  resultTwo = $('div:eq(1)'),
  resultThree = $('div:eq(2)');
  font = font || $('div.font').attr('title').toLowerCase();

resultOne.removeClass().addClass(inputOne + ' someclass ' + font);
resultTwo.removeClass().addClass(inputTwo + ' someclass ' + font);
resultThree.removeClass().addClass(inputThree + ' someclass ' + font);

}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried (how you define the function, how you attach it as a handler...)

Comment: This looks like something almost simple but I'm not sure I get the question exactly (too many words, not enough code)... Anyway, you can easily test the type of a parameter in javascript (jQuery uses this trick very often). It's also easy to know the size of args.

Comment: Like Jan Dvorak said, paste whatever you've tried so we can help you out.

Comment: ok, i added the basic code of my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than pass your function directly to the event registration, you pass an anonymous function that then calls your function with the desired arguments.

So, rather than this:

```
$("#myButton").click(callMyFunction);
```

You use this which allows you to specify the exact arguments you want:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    callMyFunction(myParam1, myParam2);
});
```

If you want to preserve, the value of `this` in your function, then you need to use `.call()` like this to explicitly set it appropriately in your function:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    fontSelection.call(this, myParam1, myParam2);
});
```

Or, just pass it as an argument and use the argument in your function instead of `this`:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    fontSelection(this, myParam1, myParam2);
});
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it was not working.  In the body of my function, I'm setting the font like tihs:  font = font || $(elem).attr('title').toLowerCase().   When the class of the body is used, the function still wants to evaulate toLowerCase of undefined

Comment: @user1798630 - You were probably losing the value of 'this' in your `fontSelection` function.  See the part I added at the end of my answer to cause `this` to be set properly in your function or passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size: A function that, if given an argument, sets the font to be used. If the argument is not set, then reads the body tag for a font.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('your class for onload change')) {
        // change font
    } else {
        $('button').click(your_function);
    }
});
```

Edit:

if you want to use `this` in your function and want it to reference on body in first case and some another dom element in second case, you can use `call` or `apply`

```
$(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('your class for onload change')) {
        fontSelection.apply($('body').get(0), [font]);
    } else {
        $('button').click(function () {
            fontSelection.apply(this, [font]);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i added my function above.  when i try this, i get cannot call toLowerCase of undefinied... (that only makes sense if you see my function above)